# get child('id') having a particular style in jquery?

Tags: jquery

how do i get the id child div whose style is **display:block**

```
<div id="mainDiv">
  <div id="step-3" style="display: none;">
  <div id="step-4" style="display: none;">
  <div id="step-5" style="display: none;">
  <div id="step-6" style="display: block;">
</div>

$(function(){
  var id= $("#parent").children("div")..... (im stuck).
})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `:visible` selector to achieve your objective.

Try,

```
var id = $("#parent").children("div:visible").attr('id')
```

Please read [here](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) for more reference.

Comment: Whats the difference between your answer and Arun P Johny ?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Some people just go for the kill, anyways upvoted yours :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien Agree with you and Rajaprabhu +1 from myside too.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector

```
var id= $("#parent").children("div:visible").attr('id')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `attr=val` selector as well

```
$(function(){
    var id= $("#mainDiv div[style='display: block;']").attr("id");
    alert(id);
})
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/U95h2/)

Or you can better use `*=` which will search for a sub string instead of matching the string like

```
$("#mainDiv div[style*='display: block;']").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use `:visible` and `.each` to loop through every elem and get the id:

```
var elemID = $("#mainDiv").find("div:visible").each(function(){
                    return this.id;
             });
```

#### note:

you don't have an id as `"#parent"` so you have to use `"#mainDiv"`.